# Working with GrailsUnitTestCase and Spock Specification in the same project

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spock

I have existing UnitTests written `extend`ing **grails'** `GrailsUnitTestCase`. I wrote new Unit Tests using Spock framework. Running individual Spock `Spec` with following command is fine.

```
prayag@prayag:~/gccount$ grails test-app spock: ChronicSpec
```

But running existing UnitTests throws compilation error in Spock Tests.

```
prayag@prayag:~/gccount$ grails test-app unit: ChronicUnitTest.testDefaultChronic

| Error Compilation error compiling [unit] tests: startup failed:
/home/prayag/gccount/test/unit/com/zazzercode/chronic/ChronicSpec.groovy: 45: unexpected token: } @ line 45, column 5.
       } //end of response process
       ^

1 error
```

**`ChronicSpec.groovy`** is as below

```
class ChronicSpec extends Specification {

    final public String CHRONIC_DEFAULT_METRIC  = ReportType.CHRONIC_REPORT + Constants.COLON + ChronicMetrics.DEFAULT
    final public String INDEX_NAME = "gccount"

    ChronicService chronicService

    void "when response is processed json should be created"() {

        given:
            def contentBuilder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().startObject()
            chronicService = new ChronicService()
            //other code goes here

        when:
            listener.writeJson(records, contentBuilder, "chronic")
        then:
            //assertion goes here
    } //end of response process => this is where exception is thrown
}
```

**Tools 'm using**

grails : 2.2.3

spock : 0.7

Comment: I would say first try `grails clean` and then make sure all other brackets before this test case are correct as well.

Comment: @Alidad `grails clean` couldn't help. Even `grails compile` works fine. I wonder why does it care about `Spec` as am trying to run `GrailsUnitTestCase`?

Comment: Have you tried one assertion to see if it works?

Comment: @SérgioMichels Thanks, adding `1 == 1` in `then` block works. Since the method am testing returns nothing at the moment I was ignoring the assertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am surprised this actually compiles, you cannot leave an empty "then:" block.

You need at least one assertion. As suggested by Sergio Michels, add an assertion and it should fix it.